# Does anyone know anything about "Exited Process" on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, profiling

I was doing some profiling of an app that I'm writing for my iPad and I did a Time Profile using Instruments on all of the processes.  It showed that top five results as:

- 23.3% ShaderTest (107) [that's my app]
- 21.3% Exited Process (101) [huh?!]
- 20.4% SpringBoard (15) [cool, I know what this is]
- 18.1% Exited Process (0) [I'm guessing this is the kernel, but why not call it that?]

So anyways, there's a process that is running approximately 20% and I have no idea what it is or what it's doing.  I tried searching on Google, Apple's dev site, and SO but came up dry.  I also rebooted, kill all of the apps, and rebooted again before posting these numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1, my time profile doesn't show any such processes.

Answer (score 0):

"Exited" simply means that by the time Instruments got to check the process name corresponding to the PID, that process has exited, and therefore could not be determined. The (#) is the PID. 0 is indeed the kernel, but it won't be called that because PID 0 is hidden (corresponding to the underlying Mach kernel_task).

A better approach would be to take a snapshot of all the processes right before profiling. That still won't guarantee no processes will exit during the profiling operation, as said operation takes time, is not atomic, and does not lock the pid list.

Hope this helps

TG